# OutOfMemory when Bitmap.createBitmap & converting to Base64

Tags: android, image, base64

Sometimes on some mobile devices, image converting to Base64 String get OutOfMemoryError because of enormous size if base64 string (when the original image & it's resize - not weight too much). Is there any way to get more modest size of string without Outofmemory exception? In my code I resize image & compress... but anyway the size of final Base64 String is large.

```
public String getBase64Image() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFileInst().getAbsolutePath(), options);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int currentWidth = options.outWidth;
        int currentHeight = options.outHeight;
        int maxSize = Math.max(currentHeight, currentWidth);
        double diff = 1;

        if (maxSize > maxAcceptableImageSize) {
            diff = (double)maxAcceptableImageSize / maxSize;
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int rotate = getCameraPhotoOrientation(getImage().getContext(), getFileInst().getAbsolutePath());
        matrix.preRotate(rotate);

        Bitmap image;
        Bitmap src = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getFileInst().getAbsolutePath()), 0, 0,
                currentWidth, currentHeight, matrix, false);
        if (diff <= 1) {
            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, (int)(src.getWidth() * diff), (int)(src.getHeight() * diff), false);
        } else {
            image = src;
        }

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();

        String base64Str = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

        src.recycle();
        image.recycle();

        return base64Str;
    }
```

Comment: The simple solution is: do not convert it to base64. In particular, it is *very* unclear why you are creating a `data` URL from a photo.

Answer (score 0):

You should scale the image before rotating it.

If you scale it down first, there are less pixels that need to be rotated, saving memory.

You should also place `.recycle()` calls directly after you're done using them, not all at the end of the function.

As a very very VERY last resort, you could add `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application in the manifest, which will most likely give you more available memory.
For specific details on largeHeap, read the documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html